# Calculate the number of quarters between two ending dates of quarters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to calculate the number of quarters between two dates - these two dates are the end date of a quarter but they're just different in year.

`2014-12-31` and `2017-09-30`

Comment: what is expected ouput?

Comment: the question is unclear, what exactly is the input (strings? series? dataframes?) and what would be the expected output? can you provide more examples where the dates are not the end of the quarters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to quarter periods, subtract and for integers use attribute `n`:

```
d1 = pd.Timestamp('2017-09-30')
d2 = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31')

a = (pd.Period(d1, 'q') - pd.Period(d2, 'q')).n
print (a)
11
```

If need working with Periods in same year use `replace`:

```
a = (pd.Period(d2, 'q') - pd.Period(d1.replace(year=d2.year), 'q')).n
print (a)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is unclear, but mathematically, the number of quarters couls be calculated using:

```
date1 = '2014-12-31'
date2 = '2017-09-30'

d1 = pd.to_datetime(date1)
d2 = pd.to_datetime(date2)

out = (d2.year-d1.year)*4+(d2.quarter-d1.quarter)
```

output: `11`